# How to make a list of dict values I extracted to be in single line

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to write the values in a dictionary in one line as a list.

If I do this:

```
dict = [ {'Value': 'test1'},
         {'Value': 'test2'},
         {'Value': 'test3'},
         {'Value': 'test4'}]


for a in dict:
    print(a['Value'])
```

The output I get is:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Now, I want those tests to write in one line like this:
**[test1, test2, test3, test4]**

If I do this:

```
x=[]
for a in dict:
    print(a['Value'])
    x.append(a['Value'])
    print(x)
```

The output is:

```
test1
['test1']
test2
['test1', 'test2']
test3
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
test4
['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
```

How can I write the output that is in one row (it doesn't have to be a list? I just need to be able to write it in a excel cell afterwards using xlsxwriter)

Comment: The last line of the last snippet seems to be what you want. Is there some other problem?

Comment: Something like `print( [v for k,v in mydict.items()] )`

Comment: FYI it's a bad idea to use the name of a builtin `dict` as the name of a variable. Unfortunately this is a very easy mistake to make (along with naming a python file the same as a builtin module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So using some of the code you already tried:

```
x=[]
for a in dict:
    x.append(a['Value'])

line_to_print = " ".join(x)
print(line_to_print)
```

Now they should be all on the same line!

Output:

```
test1 test2 test3 test4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you want to do is remove the quotes, if I'm reading the question right, you implement the change below:

```
x=[]

for a in dict:
    x.append(a['Value'])

x1 = str(x).replace("'", "")
```

x1 would be the string of values as a list without the quotes.
If this wasn't what you meant, could you please elaborate more on what you're trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to put all the results in one line. mlion21 gave me the answer I needed. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [ {'Value': 'test1'},
         {'Value': 'test2'},
         {'Value': 'test3'},
         {'Value': 'test4'}]

result = []
for item in data:
    for val in item.values():
        result.append(val)
```

Output: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']

Answer (score 0):

you could use a comprehension with parameter unpacking to the print function:

```
data = [ {'Value': 'test1'},
         {'Value': 'test2'},
         {'Value': 'test3'},
         {'Value': 'test4'}]

print(*(d['Value'] for d in data))

test1 test2 test3 test4
```

with your own separator if needed ...

```
print(*(d['Value'] for d in data),sep=', ')

test1, test2, test3, test4
```

or make a string of it before printing:

```
print(" ".join(d['Value'] for d in data)) 

test1 test2 test3 test4
```

You can also use your own separator and enclose it in brackets:

```
print("["+", ".join(d['Value'] for d in data)+"]") 

[test1, test2, test3, test4]
```